# HTML CSS Image won't center

Tags: css, html, center, text-align

I have problem : my picture doesn't want to center despite I used `text-aligne:center;`, `display:block;` and `margin: 0 auto;`

Here is a picture

[image: http://imgur.com/a/jafpQ]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#Logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>str</title>
  <meta name="description" content=" bbbbbbb" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="bablal" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge.chrome=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body background="photo/ik.png">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="Logo">
      <img src="photo/lg.png" width="800" height="533.5">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to center? The logo?

Comment: Yes i want to center logo

Comment: Remove the explicit width set on the `img` element, and declare a `max-width` of `100%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it using `Flexbox`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="Logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/333333">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you replace the CSS from the snippet?

Comment: Oh ok, teh problem is not with the code. its with the image. The image has white space. Can you upload the logo on imgur and share the link here.

Comment: lol i told you  the image was the issue. Use this image : http://imgur.com/a/SOMsc

Answer (score 1):

change #container {max-width:1000px to width:100%}

Comment: @norbik543 please check your lg.png width. may be some transparent pixels for width will be taking the place. open lg.png via any Image Viewer and check the width.

Comment: width 1600 height 1067

Comment: @norbik543 i think your image have some transparent pixels to the right. Please crop the image using any image editing tool and try

Comment: @norbik543 I have cropped an image for you to test. Please check http://imgur.com/WVFVSy5

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.Image{
      background:#ccc;
      padding:30px;
 }
 
.img-responsive{
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin:0 auto;
     }
```

```html
 <div class="Image">
  <img src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg" class="img-responsive" title="Rafique" alt="Rafique">
</div>
```

Comment: Check now again.

Comment: Your photo is in the center

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin property of the image itself to auto on the left and right.

HTML part

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="Logo">
      <img class="centeredimage" src="photo/lg.png" width="80" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS part

```
img.centeredimage{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ja0zhnsd/

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
}

#Logo img {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

use this code this will done your job. cheers!

```html
<p style="text-align:center;">
     <img   src="yourimage.png" alt="Dev N Technologies" width=600 height=200 >
```